# Fetching From CoreData returns AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am Fetching Entity Data From coreData, That returns AnyObject, I tried A lot to convert in NSDictionary and NSArray but it Can not cast any type.`

```
    var dictData:NSDictionary?
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    // self.selectedArray = response.objectForKey("retailers") as! NSArray;
    let fetchRequest2 = NSFetchRequest()
    let entityDescription2 = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Offers", inManagedObjectContext: context)
    fetchRequest2.entity  = entityDescription2

    //fetchRequest2.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let result2 : NSDictionary = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest2) as! NSDictionary
                   print("Result:",result2)
        for result in (result2 as? NSDictionary)!{

            if let data : NSDictionary = result as? NSDictionary{

                print(data)
            }
```

Offer Entity contains No Of fields. Kindly Help. It Will Be Appreciated.

```
                print("result: ",result)
                print("dictData:",dictData)
```

`       }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`context.executeFetchRequest()` returns `[AnyObject]`, not `AnyObject`.

You need to do:

```
if let results = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest2) as? [MyObjectType] {
      for object in results {
        //do thing
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you explain [MyObjectType]

Comment: That's whatever your Entity type is.

Answer (score 1):

According to its signature `executeFetchRequest` returns always an **array** of `AnyObject`. AnyObject, because the return value can be `NSManagedObject` or `Dictionary` depending on the fetch request.

The default return value is a **non-optional** `[NSManagedObject]` so write

```
let result2 = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest2) as! [NSManagedObject]
```

the forced unwrapping of the type is safe is this case, there's no need of optional bindings.

If you are using a subclass of `NSManagedObject` you can even cast the return value to that type.

Comment: i understand it returns nsmanagedObject but can i cast nsmanagedobject into nsdictionary or nsarray? i need further explaination

Comment: It returns `[NSManagedObject]`. Don't use `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`, use the Swift native types `Dictionary` and `Array`. `[NSManagedObject]` **is** an array.

Comment: [NSManagedObject] is an array of dictionaries. You can use it as you would use any other array.